# Difference between physical and logical transactions in spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

In this spring document 
**http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html** .It talks about physical and logical transactions.I have written a very simple program to understand it

### `TransactionObject.java`

```
class TransactionObject {

    private static Connection conn;

    TransactionObject() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("DB_URL", "USER", "PASS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }

    void rollBack() {
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e) { }
    }

    void Commit() {
        try {
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) { }
    }
}
```

### `ClassMethodUnderTransactionObject.java`

```
public class ClassMethodUnderTransactionObject {
    // start fresh TransactionObject
    TransactionObject  logical= new TransactionObject();

    M2(); // call M2 use same logical object
    M3(); // call M3 use same logical object
    // For M2 and M3 it is logical transaction because both using same transaction object

    if(error){
        logical.rollBack();  
    } else {
        logical.Commit(); 
    }

    // create another instance of TransactionObject
    TransactionObject  physical=new TransactionObject();

    M4(); // call M4 use different TransactionObject object
    if(error){
        physical.rollBack();  
    } else {
        physical.Commit(); 
    }
```

So M4 uses physical transaction in respect to  M2 and  M3 becuase M4 uses different trasnactionObject

Is that the way we should understand ?Is there more to understand.Please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

I understand this like this

- `physical transaction` is from external world
- `logical transaction` is your internal.

This has many consequences described in documentation.

I dont get your example.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-propagation-required), `PROPAGATION.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` creates a new transaction if a transaction doesn't exist yet or uses an existing one if one already exists.

Suppose we already have a transaction running and are going to apply a transaction to `methodA`, `methodB` and `methodC` in one of our services.

In this scenario, `methodA`, `methodB`, `methodC` will be running in logical transactions while there will be only one physical transaction which encapsulates all other logical transactions. All these logical transaction scopes are logically independent from the physical transaction scope. But they are mapped to the same physical transaction.

So: logical transaction of `methodA` + logical transaction of `methodB` + logical transaction of `methodB` -> `physical transaction`

Every logical transaction can define its separate rollback rules. Once the rollback rule triggered from logical transaction, an `UnexpectedRollbackException` is thrown but the physical transaction can still call commit because the physical transaction is independent from the scope of the logical transaction. But when the physical transaction encounters `UnexpectedRollbackException` (which is an unchecked `RuntimeException`), it triggers the rollback of the entire physical transaction and the client will see that a rollback occurred.