# Spring opens a new transaction for each JpaRepository method that is called within an @Transactional annotated method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have a method that is annotated with `@Transactional`. That should mean that any database queries that are fired within this method should all use the same transaction. But in reality that doesn't happen. What does happen is that a transaction is opened for the method itself but then when the first `JpaRepository` method is called a new transaction is opened for that particular method call.

To make matters more complex, For custom repository methods this new transaction is **only** opened when the `JpaRepository` or the `JpaRepository custom method` is annotated with `@Transactional` as well.
If not i get the following trace log statement about it:

> No need to create transaction for
> [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findFirstByIdNotNull]:
> This method is not transactional.

So it doesn't create a new transaction but it also doesn't seem to use the transaction created by the calling method either.

Heres the repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface LanguageDao extends JpaRepository<Language, Long> {

@Transactional
public Language findByLanguageCode(String languageCode);

public Language findByIdNotNull();

}
```

Heres the method that uses different repository methods.

```
@Transactional
public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
    languageDao.findByLanguageCode(); //This custom method opens a new transaction, but only because i've annotated this method with @Transactional as well.
    languageDao.findAll(); //This one as well because its a standard JpaRepository method.
    languageDao.findByIdNotNull();//This custom method doesn't because it lacks its own @Transactional annotation.
}
```

Heres the @Configuration file, with transaction management and jpa repositories enabled

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"DAOs"}, transactionManagerRef = "customTransactionManager", enableDefaultTransactions = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class RootConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Bean(name = "customTransactionManager")
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        if (shouldCreateInitialLuceneIndex) { 
            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            createInitialLuceneIndex(entityManager);
            entityManager.close();
        }
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Relevant `application.properties` settings

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view = false
```

A bit of actual logs. The first line shows that a transaction for the method `afterSingletonsInstantiated` is created.

```
[TRACE] 2021-11-08 15:32:40.811 [main] TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [config.StartupChecks$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$134b7631.afterSingletonsInstantiated]
[INFO ] 2021-11-08 15:32:40.815 [main] StartupChecks - Calling sequence table reset procedure
[DEBUG] 2021-11-08 15:32:40.833 [main] SQL - {call RESET_SEQUENCE_TABLE_VALUES_TO_LATEST_ID_VALUES()}
[INFO ] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.087 [main] StartupChecks - Sequence tables reset call finished!
[INFO ] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.087 [main] StartupChecks - doing stuff
[INFO ] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.087 [main] StartupChecks - testing!
[TRACE] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.087 [main] TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
[DEBUG] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.088 [main] SQL - select language0_.id as id1_77_, language0_.dateCreated as datecrea2_77_, language0_.englishLanguageName as englishl3_77_, language0_.languageCode as language4_77_, language0_.rightToLeft as righttol5_77_, language0_.translatedLanguageName as translat6_77_ from languages language0_
[TRACE] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.091 [main] TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
[INFO ] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.091 [main] StartupChecks - end test!
[TRACE] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.091 [main] TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByLanguageCode]
[DEBUG] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.112 [main] SQL - select language0_.id as id1_77_, language0_.dateCreated as datecrea2_77_, language0_.englishLanguageName as englishl3_77_, language0_.languageCode as language4_77_, language0_.rightToLeft as righttol5_77_, language0_.translatedLanguageName as translat6_77_ from languages language0_ where language0_.languageCode=?
[TRACE] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.113 [main] TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByLanguageCode]
[TRACE] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.113 [main] TransactionInterceptor - No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findFirstByIdNotNull]: This method is not transactional.
[DEBUG] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.115 [main] SQL - select authority0_.ID as id1_7_, authority0_.dateCreated as datecrea2_7_, authority0_.NAME as name3_7_ from AUTHORITY authority0_ where authority0_.ID is not null limit ?
[TRACE] 2021-11-08 15:32:41.120 [main] TransactionInterceptor - No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findFirstByIdNotNull]: This method is not transactional.
```

Here is a list of the things that i've already tried.

1. Annotate `languageDao` with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS) or
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED). `NESTED` isn't supported by hibernate and thus this causes an error, This error remains even when i set nestedTransactionAllowed to `true` on the transactionmanager. The setting `SUPPORTS` is ignored. The repository still starts a new transaction for each method that is called. (Update: `Propagation.MANDATORY` has no effect either)
2. I've named my transactionmanager `customTransactionManager` and added this as a parameter to @EnableJpaRepositories like so: `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"DAOs"}, transactionManagerRef = "customTransactionManager")`
3. I've set `enableDefaultTransactions` of `@EnableJpaRepositories` to `false`. This causes default methods like `findAll()` and `save()` to no longer be executed in a transaction by default. However it doesn't force them to use the transaction of the calling method that was annotated with `@Transactional`.

So my question is: How do i make the (custom) jpa repositories use the transaction that was started by the calling method?

EDIT: Here [JPA - Spanning a transaction over multiple JpaRepository method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802031/jpa-spanning-a-transaction-over-multiple-jparepository-method-calls) a similar problem is described. According to the user spring only uses the existing transaction when the repository implements `Repository` instead of `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`. But this is a workaround.

EDIT 2: My @Transactional annotations keep working when i remove `@EnableTransactionManagement`. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046116/spring-boot-with-spring-transactional-works-without-enabling-transactional-mana) that can occur when i use `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` or `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as a dependency`, which i do. Could these dependencies somehow interfere with the normal working of the transaction manager?

Comment: Not saying it would make a difference, but did you check if you are importing the same `@Transactional` everywhere (There are 2: the JPA one and the Spring one)?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I just checked. It uses the `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` one.

Comment: I suspect everything just works and you are just thrown off by the fact you have TRACE logging enabled.

Comment: @M.Deinum what do you mean exactly? I deliberately turned TRACE on by setting `logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor` to `TRACE` so that i could check whether a transaction was created by the annotated method. This turned out to be the case, but de JpaRepository methods are doing the same according to the log. They need to use the transaction opened by the calling method, not start their own.

Comment: For the full picture you should enable debug/trace logging for `org.springframework.transaction`. You are now only looking at a single part of the logging. Also if you want your `customTransactionManager` to be used you need to specify that in the `@Transactional` annotation, else it will use the default one. Another tip ditch `@Repository` on your interface, it doesn't do anything, I would also remove hte `@Transactional` (that doesn't add anything either).

Comment: @M.Deinum isn't @Repository necessary for component scanning to work? If i remove @Transactional from the repository i'll get more of these `This method is not transactional.`. You should look at the implementation of `SimpleJpaRepository`. Every method in that implementation is annotated with `@Transactional` and the class itself is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`. Putting @Transactional at the class level ensures that all of my custom jpa methods also get this annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum `org.springframework.transaction` doesnt work btw, Only `logging.level.org.springframework.transaction` does. Perhaps because i'm not using Logback but Log4J2 for logging.

Comment: I was stating the name of the package **not** the name of the property. No `@Repository` isn't needed on a Spring Data repository that uses different means to determine those. And as stated you are using `customTransactionManager` for JPA not the default `transactionManager` when nothing is specified it will use the default, except for Spring Data JPA as that internally manages the tx (that is the hint in `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Main issue here is multiple transaction managers and using them mixed together.

Comment: @Maurice - can you add the code for Language entity as well. It will become easier to test.

Comment: @Shailendra there is no problem with the language entity. The same problem occurs when calling the method of any jpa repository i have.

Comment: @Maurice that is due to the multiple transaction managers and not specifing which one to use.

Comment: @M.Deinum i just renamed the transactionmanager to 'transactionManager' i also reset the parameters of `@EnableTransactionManagement`. `@Transactional` is now explicitly using transactionmanager as the manager.  But despite all of this the individual method calls are still creating their own transactions!

Comment: @M.Deinum this is what the documentation says about `@Repository`. `As of Spring 2.5, this annotation also serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.`. So it does have its use. It helps with autodetection.

Comment: Trust me it doesn't in this case as (and as stated before) Spring Data has other means. If that stil doesn't work (as it should do) you aren't giving the full picture here. Also why the custom transaction manager? Why that setup why not use the default one? Basically I don't get your setup and you are probably leaving things out of this question.

Comment: @M.Deinum what more information do you need then? I've already posted the code of the TransactionManager, the hibernate settings etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt at understanding your problem. I would recommend enabling extra debug

```
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager=DEBUG
```

My test Service class - note that this is marked as transactional - for now that's the only place it is put as that's what we intend - to create a transactional boundary.

```
@Service
public class LanguageService {

    @Autowired
    private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void runAllMethods() {
        languageRepository.findByLanguageCode("en");
        languageRepository.findAll();
        languageRepository.findByIdNotNull();
    }

}
```

Next is the repository - there are no transactional annotations.

```
public interface LanguageRepository extends JpaRepository<Language, Long> {

    public Language findByLanguageCode(String languageCode);

    public Language findByIdNotNull();

}
```

Now on hitting the service via a controller - I get below logs. Notice the line where it says "Creating new transaction with name [com.shailendra.transaction_demo.service.LanguageService.runAllMethods]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT" - meaning that the transaction was created at the beginning of method invocation.

Also note the statement "Participating in existing transaction" which indicates that method is participating in transaction.

```
2021-11-09 11:43:06.061 DEBUG 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(2084817241<open>)] for JPA transaction
2021-11-09 11:43:06.061 DEBUG 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [com.shailendra.transaction_demo.service.LanguageService.runAllMethods]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2021-11-09 11:43:06.069 DEBUG 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3107a702]
2021-11-09 11:43:06.069 TRACE 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.shailendra.transaction_demo.service.LanguageService.runAllMethods]
2021-11-09 11:43:06.099 TRACE 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByLanguageCode]: This method is not transactional.
Hibernate: select language0_.id as id1_0_, language0_.date_created as date_cre2_0_, language0_.english_language_name as english_3_0_, language0_.language_code as language4_0_, language0_.right_to_left as right_to5_0_, language0_.translated_language_name as translat6_0_ from language language0_ where language0_.language_code=?
2021-11-09 11:43:06.333 DEBUG 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(2084817241<open>)] for JPA transaction
2021-11-09 11:43:06.333 DEBUG 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2021-11-09 11:43:06.333 TRACE 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
Hibernate: select language0_.id as id1_0_, language0_.date_created as date_cre2_0_, language0_.english_language_name as english_3_0_, language0_.language_code as language4_0_, language0_.right_to_left as right_to5_0_, language0_.translated_language_name as translat6_0_ from language language0_
2021-11-09 11:43:06.348 TRACE 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
2021-11-09 11:43:06.348 TRACE 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findByIdNotNull]: This method is not transactional.
Hibernate: select language0_.id as id1_0_, language0_.date_created as date_cre2_0_, language0_.english_language_name as english_3_0_, language0_.language_code as language4_0_, language0_.right_to_left as right_to5_0_, language0_.translated_language_name as translat6_0_ from language language0_ where language0_.id is not null
2021-11-09 11:43:06.348 TRACE 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.shailendra.transaction_demo.service.LanguageService.runAllMethods]
2021-11-09 11:43:06.348 DEBUG 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2021-11-09 11:43:06.348 DEBUG 24956 --- [nio-8181-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(2084817241<open>)]
```

For readonly methods - like findAll - you would see "No need to create transaction" - that's because although the default Repository implementation "SimpleJpaRepository" is  marked as transactional - the readonly methods are not marked transactional.

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID> {
```

Comment: Thank you @Shailendra for this answer. After including `JpaTRansactionManager=DEBUG` i too see the log `participating in existing transaction`. But i also see that it still opens a new transaction for `findAll`. You can see the same in your log excerpt. Just look at the ninth line counted from the top. It starts with `2021-11-09 11:43:06.333 TRACE 24956 --- `. It clearly says that it is opening a new transaction for findAll even though it says `Participating in existing transaction` just before that. Why does it do this? Are these nested transactions or something?

Comment: I understand now what is happening. After doing some more research and reading the spring documentation about transactions https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction i now understand that the new transaction that is opened for `findAll` is actually a `logical transaction` and not a `physical` one. So the jpa method does use the physical transaction that was created by the calling method.

Answer (score 3):

Experienced same issue while having multiple datasources, hence multiple transaction managers. Apparently the problem was that service methods marked `@Transactional` used the primary transaction manager, while the repositories were configured to use custom transaction manager:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackageClasses = {
        MyRepository.class
    },
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "customEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "customTransactionManager"
)
```

Solved the issue using spring's annotation on service methods with `transactionManager` param specified `@Transactional(transactionManager = "customTransactionManager")`

Answer (score 0):

After having tried different things, including using a `TransactionTemplate` i've settled for the following solution:

First i've turned off the default transaction policy for the jparepository methods by annotating a `configuration` class with the following:

`@EnableJpaRepositories(enableDefaultTransactions = false)`

`enableDefaultTransactions = false` causes any inherited method of JpaRepository to stop creating a transaction whenever they're called. Only jpa methods that are explicitly annotated with `@Transactional` will continue to create a new transaction when called.

All the other ones will now use any transaction that is started by the calling method, for instance a service method that is annotated with `@Transactional`.

This isn't obvious though because the `This method is not transactional` log trace message will still be generated for any jpa method that isn't explicitly annotated with @Transactional. This can be a bit confusing.

However i've proven that these methods really do use the transaction of the calling method by testing it with the following custom update method.

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.userStatus = 1 WHERE u.userStatus = 0")
public void resetActiveUserAccountsToStatusOffline();
```

Such a method *needs* to have a transaction or else the exception `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query` is thrown. But as you can see this jpa method wasn't annotated with `@Transactional` so it really did use the transaction that was started by the calling service method.

There is one small disadvantage to setting `enableDefaultTransactions = false` and that is that the transaction type of inherited methods like `findAll` will not always use a transaction that is read only. This really depends on whether the service level transaction is readonly or not. However you could still override the findAll method and explictly annotate it with `Transactional(readOnly = false)`. Another thing to beware of is that any calling method must always be annotated with @Transactional or the jpa method will run outside a transaction.

I think the advantage far outweighs these small disadvantages though. Because it is very costly performance wise when a new transaction is created for every jpa method call. So this is the solution i'll settle for right now.

To test your own transactions you'll need to add this to your application.properties

`logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE`

If the setting doesn't work please add `Log4j2` to your project.

EDIT:

These additional transactions that are opened by the JpaMethods are only `logical transactions` when a `physical transaction` has already been created by the calling method. More about this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction
These jpa methods still use the transaction created by the calling method.

The last answer in this SO thread also explains the difference between logical and physical transactions well: [Difference between physical and logical transactions in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731524/difference-between-physical-and-logical-transactions-in-spring)